# Getting last elements along an axis in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

I need a function to get last elements along an axis in numpy array.

For example, If I have a array,

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
```

The function should work like

```
get_last_elements(a, axis=0)
>>> [3]
get_last_elements(a, axis=1)
>>> [1, 2, 3]
```

This function needs to work for multidimensional array too:

```
b = np.array([[1, 2],
              [3, 4]])

get_last_elements(b, axis=0)
>>> [[2],
     [4]]
get_last_elements(b, axis=1)
>>> [3, 4]
```

Does anyone have a good idea to achieve it?

Comment: Are you sure you want `get_last_elements(a, axis=1)` to work for the first example? Since `a` is of shape `(3,)`, not `(1, 3)`.

Comment: Kindly post your attempt.

Comment: Yes. I want that. But, maybe I can convert 1d array to 2d with X = np.reshape(X,(1, X.size)) or something easily.

Comment: `np.take` may be useful.  `np.atleast_2d` may help when dealing with a 1d input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.take` to get that:

```
def get_last_elements(a, axis=0):
  shape = list(a.shape)
  shape[axis] = 1
  return np.take(a,-1,axis=axis).reshape(tuple(shape))
```

output:

```
print(get_last_elements(b, axis=0))
[[3 4]]

print(get_last_elements(b, axis=1))
[[2]
 [4]]
```